# How to add interval partition to an existing table in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, partitioning

I have a scenario in which want to partition an existing Oracle table using interval partitioning. I don't know what is the best approach in the database to do the same.

Table size is around 11 GB. Partitioning needs to be done on Date column with the interval of 1 month.

Comment: Alternative solution to partitioning is "data archiving". Its common used, cause you don't need all the data all the time - only the "current"(you have to decide the "current" definition). How its done - create separate schema for "old data", create job - it will do the archiving on your preferred frequency. Of course, there are some drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the table:

1. Rename your current table to something like `<your-table-name>_OLD`
2. Create a new partitioned table with your original table name.
3. Insert your table data from the old table to the new table.
4. Drop the old table.

Precondition: you have the required space available in your database.

And don't forget to recreate all needed constraints etc.

Or use Oracle's online table redefinition mechanism: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-6054142E-207A-4DF0-A62A-4C1A94DD36C4

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doing the same. Seems to be a tedious approach, looking for an alternative simpler method. Any suggestions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oracle version is 12c R1, apologizing it is mentioned in Oracle 11g in tags.

Comment: using "https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-6054142E-207A-4DF0-A62A-4C1A94DD36C4" approach. Getting error SQL Error: ORA-14006: invalid partition name
14006. 00000 -  "invalid partition name"
*Cause:    a partition name of the form <identifier> is
           expected but not present.
*Action:   enter an appropriate partition name. Please confirm can we use this approach in 12c R1 or is it only available in 12c R2?

Comment: @Tajinder: as the title of that manual indicates: it is for 12.2 so that feature is only available starting with 12.2. It's not available in earlier releases

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, got it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only partition the new data and let the old table as one partition you may usi this ismple approach withou reorganisation and required twice space.

0) This is your sample data , ID id the partition column defined up to 10.000

```
create table my_tab
(id number,
vc1 varchar2(100));

insert into my_tab(id,vc1)
select  rownum id, 'xxx'||rownum vc1 from dual connect by level <= 10000;
commit;
```

1) create empty interval partitione dtable with one partition covering all your data - here ID less then 10.001

```
create table my_part_tab 
(id number,
vc1 varchar2(100))
PARTITION BY RANGE (id)
INTERVAL (1000)
(PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (10001));
```

2) Define identical indexes on the partition table as on the original table

3) Exchange your table with the initial partition.

```
alter table my_part_tab exchange partition P1
with table my_tab
including indexes;
```

Now your original table is empty and all data are in the partition `P1`of the partitioned table.
New data (higher keys) would be stored based on the interval partition policy.

Comment: This answer covers Oracle 11g (as originally labeled) in 12c other possibilities of on-line reorg are [available](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-5FDB7D59-DD05-40E4-8AB4-AF82EA0D0FE5)

Comment: Thanks. please confirm mentioned approach is available in 12c R1 or not? As i am getting error SQL Error: ORA-14006: invalid partition name
14006. 00000 -  "invalid partition name"
*Cause:    a partition name of the form <identifier> is
           expected but not present.
*Action:   enter an appropriate partition name.

Comment: @Tajinder online reorganisation works only starting from 12.2. The off-line approach in my asnwer safely works from 11g;)

Comment: Thanks got your point, however, I want to partition existing data also and on the date column with the interval of one month.